# Displaying static hyperlink in grid view for Specific value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to display hyperlink for the values from SQL DB for the column name Nature.
I am able to statically display the links for the specific values of Nature.

But for certain values I should be able to display just value without any Hyper link.

If the value of nature is

1. A or B or C : Link should be "http://www.this.is.test1"
2. X or Y or Z : Link should be "http://www.this.is.test2"
3. P or Q or R : No ink should be Displayed Just value should be 
   displayed(Filed should be text , not hyperlink field).

Output on the page should be :

Nature Link(Column name on page)

1. If value is A -----> A (When Clicked on 'A' link http://www.this.is.test1 should open )
2. If value is Q -----> Q (No link, Text field.)

I am not able to display the only text Value (For PQR) and it always appear as a Link.

Tried

Using HyperlinkField in Gridview :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nature"><ItemTemplate><asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" ID="nature" NavigateUrl='<%# stauslink_RowDataBound(Eval("nature") as string) %>' Text='<%# Eval("nature") %>' runat="server" /></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
```

Code :

```
Protected string stauslink_RowDataBound(string sts)
        {
            string stslink = "http://www.this.is.test";

            switch (sts)
            {
                case "A":
                case "B":                
                case "C":
                    stslink = "http://www.this.is.test1";
                    break;              
                default:
                    break;
            }

            return stslink;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you want to display different controls for two distinct cases. You can program these as such: **Show the link in one case, show the text in the other case.**

To completely hide the respective other option, use a hyperlink and placeholder control like this (in the aspx file)

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Visible="<%# Item.MyCondition %>" Text="Click here!" NavigateUrl="<%#: Item.MyLinkUrl %>" />
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="<%# !Item.MyCondition %>">
    <span class="xyz">
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="You may not click here!"></asp:Literal>
    </span>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Using the `span` allows for custom styling of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Update `stauslink_RowDataBound` method as below

```
protected string stauslink_RowDataBound(string sts)
{
    if (sts == "A" || sts == "B" || sts == "C")
        return "http://www.this.is.test1";
    else if (sts == "X" || sts == "Y" || sts == "Z")
        return "http://www.this.is.test2";
    else
        return string.Empty;
}
```

In `GridView` update `TemplateField` as below, you will have `Visible` property based on link value

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nature">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" ID="nature" NavigateUrl='<%# stauslink_RowDataBound(Eval("nature") as string) %>' Text='<%# Eval("nature") %>' Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stauslink_RowDataBound(Eval("nature") as string)) %>' runat="server" />
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("nature") %>' Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(stauslink_RowDataBound(Eval("nature") as string)) %>'></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```